# The expanded size of the tensor (300) must match the existing size (77) at non-singleton dimension 0. Target sizes: [300]. Tensor sizes: [77]

Tags: embed

I am trying to get vectors from `glove.42B.300d.txt` and I have the problem.

1432917 300

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 124, in main
    os.path.join(args.glove, 'glove.42B.300d'))
  File "/home/dm/lili/treelstm.pytorch-master/treelstm/utils.py", line 37, in load_word_vectors
    idx += 1
```

> RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (300) must match the
>   existing size (77) at non-singleton dimension 0.  Target sizes: [300].
>   Tensor sizes: [77]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding '0' at the end of the tensor.